# TYPO3 sys_language_mode = content_fallback doesn't work on menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I've just learned how to use "sys_language_mode = content_fallback" and as far as see it works like a charm. I am using TYPO3 6.0.6 with content_fallback and for content elements its working all over my installation.

But, and that's my issue at the moment, i couldn't get it to work with my menus. All menus are allways switching back to the original "default" language.

First reflex was to use a workaround in HMENU, but there's no way to select by language and now I am stuck for two days.

Hope anybody has an idea...

Thank a lot, really appreciate any help.

Cheers!

Due to the last question, please find below more informationen:

Setup is currently:

```
english = id:0;
spanish = id:1;
spanish (america) = id:2;

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 2,1
[global]
```

So the idea is that spanish america falls back to spanish, which works - but no for the menu, only for content. I've the same issue in TYPO3 4.5 LTS...

Comment: If you set sys_language_mode = content_fallback, you want to fallback to the default language. Do you mean that pages you translated are not getting correctly displayed in the menu?

Comment: Setup is currently:
english = id 0;
spanish = id 1;
spanish (america) = id 2;

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 2,1
[global]

So the idea is that spanish america falls back to spanish, which works - but no for the menu, only for content.

Comment: Do you see the menu but on the wrong language OR you do not see some menu, but you need to see them? Pls extend your question with an example for the menu.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.
yes, menu shows up - but in the original "Default" language. Content uses the fallback language, but the menu doesn't. So in my case, if you user selects "spanish (america) = id:2" the content is "spanish = id:1", but the menu "english = id:0;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your actual code, it is wrong. You have to set `config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 1`, since you are already in language "2" and the right top level object for this configuration is "config".

Edit:

This is a known TYPO3 Bug. A patch is provided in the [TYPO3 Bugtracker](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/17354) for now.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Sorry, i've cutted my code down to keep it small - config is currently config.sys_language_mode. Cheers!

Comment: Well then i assume, it is a TYPO3 core bug. I know one hanging around in the Bugtracker since 6 (!) Years. Have a look at it: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/17354

You can apply the latest patch set provided in the issue, or you can try upgrading to TYPO3 6.1, which shouldn't be too hard and is recommended anyways. I've tested the content_fallback in version 6.1, and it worked.

Comment: Hello Shufla, thanks for your answer. updating to 6.1.1 didn't solve the problem. are you running 6.1.1 with content_fallback working? Cheers

Comment: There are some bugs in this area, please either wait for future bugfix releases or actively test the provides patches and leave feedback in gerrit.

Comment: @lufi yes i have it working with 6.1.1. I think you have to post more detailed TypoScript-Configuration.

Comment: @Shuffla. Now it works - I didn't applied the 6.2LTS Patch which solves the bug. Thanks mate, you made my day. :- )

Comment: @lufi Great, i edited my answer with the information for the patch.