# content_fallback works for a content element but not for menus

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I have the similar problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149661/typo3-sys-language-mode-content-fallback-doesnt-work-on-menu) but this didn't helped me. I am using TYPO 3 CMS 6.2.14. My aim is to change any page content with a certain language (lets say chinese) to English (id=1) if it is not translated (i mean if the content is not translated to chinese). My default language is german. With 'content_fallback', content elements is working fine(means contents are translated to english: [see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5CAh.jpg)) but not the menu. It always change to default (German). So far the code is like this :

```
#Sprache- Chinesisch
[globalVar = GP:L = 11]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 11
        language = cn
        locale_all = cn_CN.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="cn"
        sys_language_mode = content_fallback; 1,0
        sys_language_fallBackOrder=1,0
    }
[global]
```

Thank you in advance.

Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the solution. I got [this extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/languagefallback/Introduction/Index.htm) which helped me.

Anyway Thanks